# Multi-threading with classes in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, objective-c++

I have a problem with threads in C++. I want to create threads consisting of class member method with a specific object assigned. What is more, an object of another user-defined class is passed to that method. Please find the code below:

```
Grid an_chan(NX, NY, xmax, ymax);
an_chan.calc_paraFlow(anode);

Grid *ptr_grid = &an_chan;    

Variable T(Tin, Tinit, lambda_m, rho_m, Cp_m);
Variable *ptr_T = &T;

std::thread first (&Variable::initialize, ptr_T, ptr_grid);

first.join();
```

Here is the initialize method prototype:

```
void Variable::initialize(Grid& grid_obj)
```

Before I tried to add the thread, everything worked just right.

I am just wondering if this is not a compiler issue? Maybe something is wrong with my code I can not notice? Any possible fixes? 
Below I included the error returned by the compiler. As you can see I am using TDM GCC 5.1.0. I was using it with threads before and everything was working quite ok.

> In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/thread:39:0,
>                    from main.cpp:13:
>   C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/functional: In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple(chal::Variable, chal::Grid)>':
>   C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/thread:142:59:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (chal::Variable::*)(chal::Grid&); _Args = {chal::Variable&, chal::Grid&}]'
>   main.cpp:45:61:   required from here
>   C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/functional:1505:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of(chal::Variable, chal::Grid)>'
>          typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
>                                                                ^
>   C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/functional:1526:9: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of(chal::Variable, chal::Grid)>'
>            _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)

Comment: This snippet doesn't compile for many reasons. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @bloody I only want  to know, how I should pass an object, which is meant to be an argument for the Variable::initialize() method, that is all I ask about

Comment: @acraig5075 sorry, that was a typo

Comment: You're passing a pointer to `Variable::initialize(Grid&)`, what you need is to pass a reference: `std::thread first (&Variable::initialize, ptr_T, std::ref(an_chan));`

Comment: @MikevanDyke Your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `initialize` function takes it's parameter by reference you should wrap the argument in `std::ref`.

```
std::thread first(&Variable::initialize, ptr_T, std::ref(*ptr_grid));
```

Answer (score -1):

As @acraig5075 mentioned:

> The second parameter to the std::thread constructor should be a pointer to the object. You're dereferencing ptr_T.

After this you might also want to bind the function before passing to thread:

```
std::thread first(std::bind(&Variable::initialize, ptr_T, *ptr_grid));
```

Comment: This fixes the syntax error, but it passes the grid by value, so changes made by `initialize` won't show up in the original object.

Comment: Note, also, that the quoted text is incorrect. When the first argument to the thread constructor is a pointer-to-member-function, the second argument can be an object, a reference to an object, or a pointer to an object. `*ptr_T` would not be a syntax error, although it could well be a logic error.